# No Ones Been Able to Override my Wordpress Rewrite Rule Issue!

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, htaccess, rewrite-rules

I'll try to keep this quick; for (literal) months, now, I've tried dozens of ways to create my own permalinks, for example:

```
www.mycoolsite.com/Burger/Hot
```

would really load the URL as

```
www.mycoolsite.com?Burger=Hot
```

The latest "progress", I've installed Monkeyman rewrite checking plugin, and it shows that when I load "www.mycoolsite.com/Burger/Hot", it was using the following Rule and Match i'd provided:

```
Rule Pattern: Burger/([^/]+)/?$   ||   Match: index.php?page_id=7&Burger=$matches[1]
```

and it returns the following Substitution when tested:

```
page_id:7, Burger:Hot
```

Here is a plugin I tried to create to intercept the Burger call from my Rewrite above, and though it does intercept the value of "Hot" and try to pass below to the $burger_type variable, the require load attempt throws a fatal error and cannot load.

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_my_vars' );
function add_my_vars( $vars ) {
$vars[] = 'Burger';
return $vars;
}


register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_flush_rewrite_rules' );
function my_flush_rewrite_rules() {
add_my_rules();
flush_rewrite_rules();
}
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, function() {
flush_rewrite_rules();
} );

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'show_places_to_visit', 1 );

function show_places_to_visit( $wp_query ) {

global $wp_query;  

  $pagename = isset($wp_query->query['Burger']) ? $wp_query->query['Burger'] : NULL;
  if (is_main_query() && $pagename != '') {

    // get our custom vars
    $burger_type = $wp_query->get('Burger');    //$wp_query->Burger

    // Override and load URL
        require('mycoolsite.com/index.php?
page_id=7&Burger='.$burger_type );

        exit(); // stop default wordpress behavior
      }
}
```

Any direction would be much appreciated, I cant launch the site until I have these SEO friendly links working. Please help.

Comment: Please, can you post the code you have been using to define the rewrite rule?

Comment: Hello cybmeta, I am currently using the Rewrite plugin from https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite/. Nothing in my functions.php was having any affect as far as rewrite rules or adding query_vars. I have tried creating a plugin which i will include in the main file, which intercepts the "Burger" call and attempts to redirect as I need, but I get fatal error on the require for my local file, "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden"

Comment: Added Plugin code i created